# How many three digit numbers exist such that the third digit is the geo mean

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> How many three digit numbers exist such that one of the digits is the geometric mean of the other two?
>   **A** 12, **B** 18, **C** 24, **D** other

So, $N = 100a + 10b + c$ let $c =\sqrt{ab}$.

$ab$ must be a perfect square, so $ab = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81$

Case: $ab = 1 \implies a=1, b=1$.

Case: $ab = 4 \implies a = 2, b=2$

Case: $ab = 9 \implies a=3, b=3$.

Case: $ab = 16 \implies (a=8, b=2), (a=4, b=4)$

Case: $ab = 25 \implies a=5, b=5$

Case: $ab = 36 \implies (a=9, b=4), (a=6, b=6)$

Case: $ab = 49 \implies (a=7, b=7)$

Case: $ab = 64 \implies (a=8, b=8)$

Case: $ab=81 \implies (a=9, b=9)$.

$(a=8, b=2, c = 4)$ also means that we could replace this with, $ (a, b, c) = (2, 4, 8) = (4, 2, 8) = (4, 8, 2)$

$(a=9, b=4, c=6)$ also means $(a, b, c) = (9, 4, 6) = (4, 6, 9) = (9, 6, 4) = (4, 9, 6) = (6, 9, 4) = (6, 4, 9)$.

So to me, the answer is **B** $18$

Comment: You forgot the cases for $ab = 4$ where $a = 1, b = 4$ (or the other way around), and the same for the case $ab = 9$

Comment: Can't see the 6 permutations of 124 in there.

Comment: $ab=16$ also implies the case of $a=2$ and $b=8$.

Comment: BTW, the answer is $26$ (i.e., D - other).

Comment: @barakmanos  I made the comment, not Frentos.  You and I were both wrong.  I overlooked the case in which $bc = 0$.  You overlooked the fact that we want the number of three digit numbers in which one of the digits is the geometric mean of the other two.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I know you made the comment. The auto-complete here mis-auto-completed me because I started with "N" instead of "F". And no, I did not overlook that case, please see my answer below... Oh... sorry, I did miss that case, since I was concentrating on OP's answer...

Comment: Already the title and the body of the post ask different questions...

Comment: @Did: Indeed. But notice that both questions have the answer D :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked two different questions.  The question in the title appears to be:

> "How many three digit numbers exist such that the third digit is the
>   geometric mean of the other two?"

I will answer the question in the statement of the problem:

> "How many three digit numbers exist such that one of the digits is the
>   geometric mean of the other two?"

Let $x, y \geq 0$.  The *geometric mean* of $x$ and $y$ is $\sqrt{xy}$.

A three digit positive integer is a number of the form $100a + 10b + c$, where $a \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ and $b, c \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.

We consider cases:

1. The geometric mean of the digits is $0 \implies 0 = \sqrt{a \cdot 0}$, where $a \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.  There are nine possibilities: $100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900$.
2. If $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, $n = \sqrt{n \cdot n}$.  There are nine such numbers.  They are $111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999$.
3. $2 = \sqrt{1 \cdot 4}$.  Then the number is one of the $3! = 6$ permutations of the digits $1$, $2$, and $4$.  They are $124, 142, 214, 241, 412, 421$.
4. $3 = \sqrt{1 \cdot 9}$.  Then the number is one of the $3! = 6$ permutations of the digits $1$, $3$, and $9$.  They are $139, 193, 319, 391, 913, 931$.
5. $4 = \sqrt{2 \cdot 8}$.  The number is one of the $3! = 6$ permutations of the digits $2$, $4$, and $8$.  They are $248, 284, 428, 482, 824, 842$.
6. $6 = \sqrt{4 \cdot 9}$.  The number is one of the $3! = 6$ permutations of the digits $4$, $6$ and $9$.  They are $469, 496, 649, 694, 946, 964$.

Hence, there are $2 \cdot 9 + 4 \cdot 6 = 42$ three digit numbers such that one of the digits is the geometric mean of the other two.

Answer (score -1):

Third digit is $\sqrt{ab}$ implies square root should yield single digit so it can be $[0,9]$ thus now digits whose product is 0 so $100,..900$ , for 1 is only $1,1$ so number $111$ then for 2 so product is $4$ thus numbers are $222,142,412$ then $3$ so $333,193,913$ now $4$ so $284,824,444$ then $5$ so $555$ then $6$ so $496,946,666,$  for $7$ so $777$ then $8$ so $888$ and finally $9$ so $999$ thus total numbers are $9+1+3+3+3+1+3+1+1+1=26$ so its $D$